# How can i deobfuscate base64 zlib when i have obfuscate method?

Tags: base64, obfuscation, zlib, deobfuscation

i have obfuscate metod

```
    ##### Obfuscator #####

    zlb = lambda in_: zlib.compress(in_)
    b64 = lambda in_: base64.b64encode(in_)

    def obfuscate_script(data: str, loop_count: int) -> str:
        # Change the value of the random variable to ensure different obfuscation strings each time

        data = data.replace(
            "RandVar = '?'", f"RandVar = '{random.randint(100000, 10000000)}'"
        )

        # Setup obfuscation

        xx = "b64(zlb(data.encode('utf8')))[::-1]"
        prefix = "_ = lambda __ : __import__('zlib').decompress(__import__('base64').b64decode(__[::-1]));"

        # Perform obfuscation

        for i in range(loop_count):
            try:
                data = "exec((_)(%s))" % repr(eval(xx))
            except TypeError as s:
                sys.exit(" TypeError : " + str(s))

        # Build the complete output

        output = ""

        output += "\n"
        output += prefix
        output += data
        output += "\n"

        # Return the output

        return output
```

and i have obfuscated code, but i dont have orginal code, how can i deobfuscate code?

top 5 deobfuscators (online), chatgpt scripts, more and more